# Переменные в процедуре не используются

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def poisk(ar, x, y, u):
  c = 0
  for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
          if ar[i][j] == u:
              c = c + 1
    if c == 2:
      for j in range(0, 3):
        if ar[i][j] == 0:
          x = i
          y = j
  c = 0
  for j in range(0, 3):
    for i in range(0, 3):
      if ar[i][j] == u:
        c += 1
      if c == 2:
        for i in range(0, 3):
          if ar[i][j] == 0:
             x = i
             y = j
  c = 0
  for j in range(0, 3):
    for i in range(0, 3):
      if ar[i][j] == u and i == j:
        c += 1
  if c == 2:
    for i in range(0, 3):
      for j in range(0, 3):
          if ar[i][j] == 0 and i == j:
            x = i
            y = j
  c = 0
  for j in range(0, 3):
    for i in range(0, 3):
      if ar[i][j] == u and i + j == 2:
        c += 1
  if c == 2:
    for i in range(0, 3):
      for j in range(0, 3):
        if ar[i][j] == 0 and i + j == 2:
          x = i
          y = j
```

в этой процедуре выводяться изначальные значения , которые почему-то никак не изменяются 
`poisk(arr, xN, yN, 2)`
выше пример вызова

Comment: Напиши какие аргументы ты вводишь при вызове poisk

Comment: массив нампая 3х3, -1, -1, 2

Comment: В функции нет оператора print

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы передаёте значение в функцию, оно сохраняется в локальную переменную внутри функции.

Поэтому если вы напишете

```
x = 0

def foo(x):
    x = 5

foo(x)
print(x)
```

То выведется всё-равно `0`. То есть функция - как Лас-Вегас. Всё, что в ней произошло, в ней и остаётся. По научному это называется "локальная область видимости".

Чтобы посчитанное внутри функции как-то получить, нужно использовать ключевое слово `return`:

```
x = 0

def foo(x):
    x = 5
    return x

x = foo(x)
print(x)
```

Этот код выведет уже `5`.

`return` можно использовать и для того, чтобы вернуть из функции несколько значений:

```
x = 0
y = 0

def foo(x, y):
    x = 5
    y = 7
    return x, y

x, y = foo(x, y)
print(x, y)
```

Этот код выведет `5 7`

Ну и нет никакой необходимости передавать в качестве аргумента те переменные, которые не участвуют в рассчётах, а только должны вычислиться в результате работы функции.

Поэтому у вас определение функции должно выглядеть так:

```
def poisk(ar, u):  # Без x и y
```

внутри функции у вас где-то должно быть

```
return x, y
```

а вызывать вашу функцию нужно как-то так:

```
xN, yN = poisk(arr, 2)
```

Comment: спасибо большое